# Javascript equation - Jackson/Pollock 3 Caliper calculator

Tags: javascript, equation

I need to calculate with javascript the Jackson/Pollock 3 Caliper equation.

The equation is this:

Html Data form for input fields:

- Age
- Caliper1 (example: 12mm)
- Caliper2 (example: 10mm)
- Caliper3 (example: 14mm)
- CaliperTot (example: Sum of Calipers = 36mm)
- Result

*BodyDensity= 1.0994921 – (0.0009929 x CaliperTot) + (0.0000023 x (square of CaliperTot ])) – (0.0001392 x Age)*

*%FatMass = (495/BodyDensity) – 450*

How to help me?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Frankie, so the only variable value is Age and everything else is fixed? Which data is the user entering.

Comment: @JuanV Hi, i have edit my post after your question. Are variable all this value: Age, Caliper1, Caliper2, Caliper3

Comment: Got it, give me a moment.

Comment: I have one doubt (English related), square in this case means caliperTot to the power of 2? If that's the case then my answer is correct, otherwise use Math.sqrt(caliperTot)

Comment: @JuanV yes, your answare is corret

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you're currently handing the inputs so this is a full working example that you could fit to your needs:

```html
<h1>Input</h1>

Enter your age: <input type="text" name="age" id="age"><br>
Caliper 1: <input type="text" name="caliper1" id="caliper1"><br>
Caliper 2: <input type="text" name="caliper2" id="caliper2"><br>
Caliper 3: <input type="text" name="caliper3" id="caliper3"><br>

<button onclick="calculate();">Calculate</button><br>

<h1>Output</h2>

Fat Mass(%): <input type="text" name="fatMass" id="result" readonly>

<script>
function calculate() {

 // get inputs
 let age = parseInt( document.querySelector('#age').value );
 let caliper1 = parseInt( document.querySelector('#caliper1').value );
 let caliper2 = parseInt( document.querySelector('#caliper2').value );
 let caliper3 = parseInt( document.querySelector('#caliper3').value );
 let caliperTot = caliper1 + caliper2 + caliper3;

 // calculate
 let bodyDensity = 1.0994921 - (0.0009929 * caliperTot) + (0.0000023 * caliperTot * caliperTot) - (0.0001392 * age);

 let fatMass = (495 / bodyDensity ) - 450;

 // show result
 document.querySelector('#result').value = fatMass;
}
</script>
```

It shows 4 text inputs where the user can put their data and another input to display the result. You'd need to add some checks to see if each input is valid and not empty.